# list.files output, locale dependency

Tags: r, locale

I was running some tests on my R package. I noticed that the order of files output by `list.files` in the console and inside `R CMD check` was different. I suspect that this is because of the locale dependency of the `sort` function discussed here:

[R CMD check fails, devtools::test() works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42272119/r-cmd-check-fails-devtoolstest-works-fine)

My question is as follows: how does one eliminate the locale dependency in `list.files` and make it produce consistent output for both interactive sessions and `R CMD check` runs?

**Reproducible example**

Inside the `testthat` folder, create the `abc` folder with the following empty files:

1. c-123.txt
2. c-456.txt
3. T.db

Inside the interactive session, `list.files` returns:

```
[1] "c-123.txt" "c-456.txt" "T.db"
```

Yet the following test fails when run using `R CMD check` because `T.db` comes first:

```
context("ls")

test_that("correct order", {
  expect_true(list.files("abc")[1] == "c-123.txt")
})
```

This test is passed when using `devtools::test_file('tests/testthat/test-ls.R')` in the console.

Comment: other option would be to log it as a bug here: https://github.com/r-lib/testthat

Comment: @MrFlick included an example.

Comment: Does order really matter? Does your package only work in certain locales? What exactly are you testing? What locale are you using in R and what locale does your system use?

Comment: The idea behind the test was to do some manipulations on one of text files in some folder. This file was fetched by list.files[1]. While I can for sure rewrite the test, it was interesting to understand what was going on with list.files. The locale business has nothing to do with my package.